# Master file conditional hide element with respect to URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, conditional-statements, master-pages

I have a page that uses **site.master** I am pulling into *facebook* by an `iframe`.
The `iframe` cuts the form off width-wise.  I can solve this by deleting the left hand menu.

In my **site.master** I have:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td class="needstogo"></td>
       <td class="keep"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If the URL in the browser reads facebook, I need the `td class="needstogo"` to be hidden.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use `$(document).ready(function(){ if(URL == "facebook") $("#needstogo").hide();})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find and style  any of the control in a child page that is inherited from master page like that:

```
ContentPlaceHolder cp = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("your site.master`s               ContentPlaceHolder name");
```

In your case just add the "id" attributes to your `<td>` tag for which you want to change the css class or want to set null. 
 i.e.

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td id="test" class="needstogo"></td>
   <td class="keep"></td>
</tr>
```

Now in code behind just put the following two lines of code in your conditional statement:

```
TableRow tr = cp.FindControl("test") as TableRow;
tr.CssClass = "";
```

hope this will help you...